# How to add library to vcxproject in project properties?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, include-path, library-path

I want to link a library file and a directory to my project, but I want to set this in project files, not from visual studio. I am running msbuild. I tried

```
    <ItemGroup>  
    <ClCompile Include="test.cpp" />  
    <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>E:\project\Debug</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <Link>
       <AdditionalDependencies>E:\project\Debug\file.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
      </Link>
    </ItemGroup>
```

but I get error MSB4035:

> the required attribute "Include" is empty or missing and LNK2019 error
>   unresolved external symbol.

Thankyou.

Comment: Just do this first with the IDE, then look at the .vcxproj file to see how to do this correctly.  You'll discover `ItemDefinitionGroup`.

Comment: I dont have the IDE installed, anyway if I put this in an <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x32'"> it will work ?

Comment: ok, not the error MSB4035 dissapeared, I only have to fix lnk2019. I think it's not reading the #include "E:\project\include\aplication.h" Thankyou